# Data delay of SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a question about Android sensor. According to the [official website guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor), the data delay of `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` is 0 microsecond. The data delay (or sampling rate) controls the interval at which sensor events are sent to your application via the `onSensorChanged()` callback method.

If I use `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`, is the interval really 0, or another very small value?

Comment: When specifying `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`, the Android kernel will execute the `goc` instruction, putting the ARM CPU in speed-of-light mode. This allows your phone to read the sensor ∞ times per second, at an interval of 0 seconds per read.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart consider post that as an answer since I didn't find any exact duplicate, and it might be useful to know the underlying system.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart according to the guide,onSensorChanged() will be called when sensor report new data,the data delay specify the interval.How it will if there is a new data between the interval.Will the method be called at the interval?or whenever the new data comes,the method will be called.